# What is the Menu Bar keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I'm trying to learn keyboard shortcuts. I cannot find a shortcut that changes focus to the menu bar. Does it exist? Similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to change to the solution explorer.

I am aware of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but I want to be able to access the whole menu bar without having to reach for my mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out myself. It is Alt + first letter of the tab.

So to access the File tab. Alt + F

Or Project tab. Alt + P